# stuck with the sql / hql query group by

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql

```
id          device_id   config_status   update_finished
1           5015001     SUCCESS     11-OCT-2012
2           5015001     SUCCESS     23-OCT-2012
3           5015001     PENDING     23-OCT-2012
4           5015001     PENDING     23-OCT-2012
5           5016222     PENDING     12-OCT-2012
6           5016222     PENDING     22-OCT-2012
```

Hi, above is my table with some example data. What I'd like to achieve is to get for each device_id last SUCCESS status (date is in update_finished field) and all PENDING statuses. From the example above the result query should have:

```
id          device_id   config_status   update_finished
2           5015001     SUCCESS     23-OCT-2012
3           5015001     PENDING     23-OCT-2012
4           5015001     PENDING     23-OCT-2012
5           5016222     PENDING     12-OCT-2012
6           5016222     PENDING     22-OCT-2012
```

So that means only the last SUCCESS status by date column update_finished and all PENDING statuses for each device_id.

Currently I'm trying to mess with GROUP BY: `SELECT device_id, config_status, max(update_finished) AS "LastUpdate"
from config_status WHERE config_status = 'SUCCESS' group by device_id, config_status`

This returns only the last SUCCESS statuses for each device_id indeed, but it misses the PENDING statuses and it doesn't have `id` column. If I add `id` field to the GROUP BY then the grouping would be by `id` anyway.

Could anyone help me with the proper query? Is it supposed to have subqueries also? In the end I need to have it as HQL, but I think it will be very similar to SQL.

**EDIT:**

Thanks everybody for helping me out. All these queries work but most fitted my the query provided by @Remigio because it was easiest to transform it into HQL query that returns me parametrized object, not just Object.

Here is my working HQL query with additional fields that I have omitted in my initial example

```
List<ConfigStatus> statuses = getHibernateTemplate().find("select c from ConfigStatus c " +
                "where (configStatus = 'SUCCESS' and updateFinished = (select max(updateFinished) from " +
                "ConfigStatus c1 where c1.device.deviceId = c.device.deviceId and c1.configStatus = 'SUCCESS' and c1.configFile.configFileId = ?)) " +
                "or configStatus = 'PENDING' and configFile.configFileId = ?", new Object[] {configFileId, configFileId});
```

Comment: It is important to know oracle version in order to take advantage of over partition analytic function.

Comment: @danihp Hi, Oracle database version is 10.2

Comment: nice, I have quoted oracle documentation sample and a version for your query. See my (not tested) answer.

Comment: @danihp Sorry, i was wrong with database version, it is actually 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
select * from device d
where (config_status='SUCCESS' and update_finished = (select max(update_finished) from
device d1 where d1.device_id = d.device_id and d1.config_status='SUCCESS'))
or config_status='PENDING'
```

Comment: Brilliant! This fits the most cause I could easily make it into HQL. I edit my post with answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on [oracle sample](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT last_name FROM 
   (SELECT last_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_name) R FROM employees)
   WHERE R BETWEEN 51 and 100;
```

Yout query should be:

```
select * from (
  SELECT device_id, config_status, update_finished AS "LastUpdate" ,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY update_finished desc) R
  from config_status WHERE config_status = 'SUCCESS' 
) where R = 1
```

**EDITED**

```
select device_id, config_status, update_finished
from (
  SELECT device_id, config_status, update_finished  ,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY update_finished desc) R
  from config_status WHERE config_status = 'SUCCESS' 
) where R = 1
union all
SELECT device_id, config_status, update_finished  
from config_status WHERE config_status = 'PENDING'
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I got the database version wrong the first time. It's actually version 11.
Your query above returns:
`device_id: 5015000` `status:SUCCESS` `last_update: 24-OCT-12` `R: 1`
Not what I was expecting. I'll looknow  at this example also

Comment: 5015000 is not in your sample data. I have only wrote hard part of query, you should union it with all other rows. see edited query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --Try This:

    with T_CONFIG_STATUS as (
      select 1 as id, 5015001 as DEVICE_ID, 'SUCCESS' as CONFIG_STATUS, TO_DATE('11-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') as update_finished from DUAL union
      select 2, 5015001, 'SUCCESS', TO_DATE('23-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') from DUAL union
      select 3, 5015001, 'PENDING', TO_DATE('23-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') from DUAL union
      select 4, 5015001, 'PENDING', TO_DATE('23-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union
      select 5, 5016222, 'PENDING', TO_DATE('12-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union
      select 6, 5016222, 'PENDING', TO_DATE('22-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') from DUAL
    )
    , q1 as (
      select id, DEVICE_ID, CONFIG_STATUS, UPDATE_FINISHED, 
        max(UPDATE_FINISHED) over(partition by DEVICE_ID, CONFIG_STATUS) as MAX_UPDATE_FINISHED    
      from T_CONFIG_STATUS
    )
    , q2 as (
      select id, device_id, config_status, update_finished, max_update_finished,
        case 
          when config_status='SUCCESS' and update_finished=max_update_finished then 'keep'
          when config_status='PENDING' then 'keep'
          else 'discard'
        end as KEEP_RECORD
      from q1
    )
    select id, device_id, config_status, update_finished
    from Q2 where KEEP_RECORD='keep'
    order by id;
```

So, the table t_config_status is nothing but a dummy table cntaining the sample data in Skyzer's problem.

The query q1 then gets the maximum update date for each record withtin the set of all records with same device_id and cojnfig_status.

The query q2 then calculates another flag todecide whether to keep or discard a record. So, it keeps each record that has PENDINGstatus. But it keeps only those records with SUCCESS status which have latest update finished date.

The final query then just uses the filter to present records with the flag value of 'keep' and ignored those with flag value of 'discard'.

Hope this clarifies the logic.